# What does 'Module' do when defining a function?

Tags: functions

I have an exercise class where I need to understand a specific function.

without posting the whole big code into here I'd like to understand the basic

```
funct[a_,b_,c_] := Module[{p,k,etest,crit}, .....  ];
```

Inside are additionally some while loops etc. but as for now I'd like to know why there is a 'Module' in front. Maybe also important is the fact that inside the curly brackets `{p,k,etest,crit}` is pretty much every single variable which occurs in the function in these while loops.

Comment: This is pretty well documented: [Module](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html), [Modules and Local Variables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModulesAndLocalVariables.html), [Blocks Compared With Modules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Module[{x,y,z}, ...]` treats whatever you define in the curly brackets as local variables. That is, you can think of them as being available only for computations carried out within the `Module[]`. When it's finished, they are no longer available in memory.

Also see the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html).

Comment: Yes thanks now I understand it!

Answer (score 5):

You need to look up module and to try a few examples. A module makes the variables in the curly brackets local to the module and does not change variables outside the module that happen to have the same name.

Try this. First I define a function that contains the local variables `a` and `b`. Then I define global values for `a` and `b`, use the function and look at the values before and after the use of the function.

```
f[x_] := Module[{a, b}, a = 3; b = 2; a + b x]

a = 5; b = 10;
{a, b, f[4], a, b}
```

> {5, 10, 11, 5, 10}

So you can see that the values of `a` and `b` that were global were not used in the module and were not effected by the local variables  `a` and `b` within the module.

Comment: Perfect your example made it clear what you meant! Thanks